# Angurlarjs: How to represent state in URL and get state back from URL?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a search app using AngularJs 1.0.8.

In order to allow bookmarking and sharing links I want to represent the current state of the search in the browser's location bar.
A URL might look like this

> http://example.com/#!/search?s="Some query term"&page=2

So the app has to do two things:

1. update the URL when someone searches
2. Restore the state when another opens the same URL

What I currently do (maybe this is the wrong approach) is:

**Configuring routeProvider to prevent the browsers from reloading on search param changes**

```
...
$routeProvider.when('/search', {
        templateUrl: 'app/search/view/List.html',
        controller: 'listCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });
...
```

**Getting search results and setting location when someone presses the search button (searchArray holds the search parameters)**

```
...
$location.search(searchArray);
...
```

**Updating the search results accordingly.**

```
...
$scope.search_results=data;
...
```

In order to restore the state I'm watching $location.search()

```
...    
$scope.$watch(function () { return $location.search() }, function (newVal) {/* evaluate params and fire query */ });
...
```

My problem is, that location always changes twice. I've managed to overcome this issue by maintaining dirty flag.

As I think this maintaining state in URL is a popular scenario, I think there must be a better approach with Angular.
Could anyone guide me in to the right direction?

Comment: $route service has a event `$routeUpdate` which you can watch in the controller when the search string changes.